# Jira SDK: atlas-create-jira-plugin fails due to Google Analytics

Tags: java, maven, plugins, proxy, jira

I am currently trying to start developing a Jira plugin. However, I needed to configure the Maven settings to use my company's proxy server. This proxy seems to block the google analytics server.

When I try to create a new plugin project following [the official tutorial](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/framework/atlassian-sdk/create-a-helloworld-plugin-project/) the step 2 (execute `atlas-create-jira-plugin`) produces the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Jira Plugins\test> atlas-create-jira-plugin
Executing: "C:\Applications\Atlassian\atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.2.7\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin\mvn.cmd" com.atlassian.maven.plugins:jira-maven-plugin:8.1.2:create -gs C:\Applications\Atlassian\atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.2.7\apache-maven-3.5.4/conf/settings.xml
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< org.apache.maven:standalone-pom >-------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jira-maven-plugin:8.1.2:create (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Google Analytics Tracking is enabled to collect AMPS usage statistics.
[INFO] Although no personal information is sent, you may disable tracking by adding <allowGoogleTracking>false</allowGoogleTracking> to the amps plugin configuration in your pom.xml
[INFO] Sending event to Google Analytics: AMPS:jira - Create Plugin
[INFO] using stable product version: 7.13.0
[INFO] using stable data version: 7.13.0
Define value for groupId: : [ERROR] Error making tracking request
java.net.UnknownHostException: www.google-analytics.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect (PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect (SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect (Socket.java:607)
    at java.net.Socket.connect (Socket.java:556)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect (NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer (HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer (HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init> (HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New (HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New (HttpClient.java:357)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient (HttpURLConnection.java:1226)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0 (HttpURLConnection.java:1205)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect (HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect (HttpURLConnection.java:990)
    at com.dmurph.tracking.JGoogleAnalyticsTracker.dispatchRequest (JGoogleAnalyticsTracker.java:463)
    at com.dmurph.tracking.JGoogleAnalyticsTracker.access$100 (JGoogleAnalyticsTracker.java:76)
    at com.dmurph.tracking.JGoogleAnalyticsTracker$1.run (JGoogleAnalyticsTracker.java:431)
```

As I said, I am pretty sure that `java.net.UnknownHostException: www.google-analytics.com` is caused by my company's proxy.

I then tried to disable google analytics. The problem is: the command does not create any project files until here and so there is no pom.xml that I could edit. When I try to edit the default Maven profile in `~/.m2/settings.xml` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25361154/11924664), Maven complains that the project does not have a pom.xml:

```
Executing: "C:\Applications\Atlassian\atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.2.7\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin\mvn.cmd" com.atlassian.maven.plugins:jira-maven-plugin:8.1.2:create -gs C:\Applications\Atlassian\atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.2.7\apache-maven-3.5.4/conf/settings.xml
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The POM for com.atlassian.maven.plugins:jira-maven-plugin:jar:8.1.2 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.268 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-06-18T15:08:01+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin com.atlassian.maven.plugins:jira-maven-plugin:8.1.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.atlassian.maven.plugins:jira-maven-plugin:jar:8.1.2 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Finally, when I try to execute `atlas-create-jira-plugin -Dallow.google.tracking=false` (also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25361154/11924664)) I am getting a similar error:

```
Executing: "C:\Applications\Atlassian\atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.2.7\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin\mvn.cmd" com.atlassian.maven.plugins:jira-maven-plugin:8.1.2:create -gs C:\Applications\Atlassian\atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.2.7\apache-maven-3.5.4/conf/settings.xml -Dallow .google.tracking=false
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.203 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-06-18T15:14:56+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\Users\KUJ5MU\Documents\Jira Plugins\test). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]    
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

Does anyone have a solution for this problem? How can I tell the Atlassian SDK not to use Google analytics *before* creating my first project?

Comment: Possibly [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25361154/944849)?

Comment: @user944849 No, I am citing this post twice. As I wrote: I have already tried all of the solutions given in the post you mentioned. None of this worked, all of them gave further errors.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore that error. you can see that error occured after "group id:". So just give ur groupid after the error and press enter. it will as k for the other settings. You can contine from there without issues.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).